# format string "YYMMDDhhmmss" to string in fomat "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a string that holds a datetime with format **"YYMMDDhhmmss"**:

```
string = "210422075308"
```

But I want to change the format of the string to get the date formatted as **"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"**

I don't know if I can use datetime strftime function or not.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

EDIT: format **"YY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"** is accepted too.

Comment: Read the documentation on Python standard library datetime module; specifically the strptime and strftime functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strptime` to *parse* your string to a datetime object, and `strftime` to *format* the parsed string to the format you want:

```
import datetime
string = "210422075308"
formatted_string = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%y%m%d%H%M%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Which will return:

```
'2021-04-22 07:53:08'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just changed the line formatted_string = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%Y%M%d%H%m%S").strftime("%Y-%M-%d %H:%m:%S") to **formatted_string = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%y%m%d%H%M%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")** and returns '2021-04-22 07:53:08'

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense indeed, sorry about that, guess i didn't validate :) I Will update my answer

Comment: you can simplify to `datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%y%m%d%H%M%S").isoformat(' ')` in Python 3.7 or higher